# Placing a text field in a Menulet in Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, menu

I'm working on an menulet-based application for the Mac that requires me to have a text field in the menu. I've searched high and low and have not found any examples of how to do this, yet I have seen many menulet apps that implement a text field. I've found no way to do it from Interface Builder, so I guess this text field would need to be defined and added to the menu programmatically.

If anyone could help me with this issue, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An NSTextField is a view based subclass, therefore in code, when you create the NSMenuItem you must use the `– setView:` property and add the NSTextField to the menu item.

Also if you use an NSStatusItem, it also has a `-setView:` property.